# Passing a list to a mixin in SASS as parameters?

Tags: compass-sass, sass

I'm trying to make a SCSS stylesheet easily configurable by defining a set of constants that will be used in a number of mixins and with the Compass library. Ideally, I'd like to be able to do the following:

```
$item-bgs: linear-gradient(white, black), #ccc;

@mixin some-mixin() {
    @include background-with-css2-fallback($item-bgs*);
}
```

The `background-with-css2-fallback` is a [Compass mixin](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/images/#mixin-background-with-css2-fallback) that accepts up to 10 params. I'm assuming that SASS does not currently support passing a list parameter as the argument list, otherwise Compass would probably use it, but I'm wondering if I can get the `$item-bgs` list to be the first 2 arguments to the `background-with-css2-fallback` mixin. Is there a way to do this currently, or is it even planned for SASS in the future?

Answer (score 1):

It may not be supported by SASS natively, but Compass does support passing a list as the first argument to the `background-with-css2-fallback` mixin. If you look at the source for the mixin, you'll see that it uses a `compact` function that handles the logic for collapsing the arguments into a single list, whether passed individually or in a single list parameter.

For example, this works fine for me:

```
@import "compass";

$item-bgs: (linear-gradient(white, black), #ccc);

.test {
    @include background-with-css2-fallback($item-bgs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Examples of useing maps as arguments:

##### Example 1 *(`list`)*

```scss
@mixin transition($property...){
    @if $property {
        transition-property: $property;
    }
    @else {
        transition-property: all;
    }
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-duration: .3s;
    transition-delay: 0;
}
.btn {
   color: black;
   border: 1px solid black;
   @include transition(color, border-color);

   &:hover {
     color: red;
     border-color: red;
   }
}
```

##### Example 2 *(`Custom params`)*

```scss
@use 'sass:meta';

@mixin example2($args...) {
    @each $key, $value in meta.keywords($args) {
        #{$key}: #{$value};
    }
}
.shape {
   @include example2($width:200px, $height:100px);
}
```

##### Example 3 *(`map`)*

```scss
@mixin colors($args:()) {
  @if length($colors) > 0 {
    @each $key, $val in $args{
      .txt-#{$key} {
        color: #{$value};
      }
      .bg-#{$key} {
        background-color: #{$value};
      }
    }
  }
}
$colors_map: (
  primary: blue,
  secondary: green,
  accent: red,
  light: white,
  dark: black
);
@include colors($colors_map);
```